# Null GoogleMap/Crashing when implementing Google Maps Android API v2 (In Xamarin)

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin

I'm currently struggling on an extremely basic implementation of the aforementioned API using Xamarin. Most of the manifest was copied from these tutorials which I cross-referenced:

http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/maps_and_location/part_2_-_maps_api/
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#obtain_a_google_maps_api_key

The Map property of my MapFragment is null and I can't figure out why. I've successfully generated an API key, and specified my package permissions, including adding the SHA-1 fingerprint/package name to the API console. Here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1"   android:versionName="1.0" package="@string/package_name">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<!-- Google Maps for Android v2 requires OpenGL ES v2 -->
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />

<!-- We need to be able to download map tiles and access Google Play Services-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<!-- Allow the application to access Google web-based services. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<!-- Google Maps for Android v2 will cache map tiles on external storage -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<!-- Google Maps for Android v2 needs this permission so that it may check the connection state as it must download data -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<!-- These are optional, but recommended. They will allow Maps to use the My Location provider. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application android:label="@string/app_name">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="@string/api_key_android" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

MAPS_RECIEVE was a permission in the tutorial, but I found that it is now obsolete here and thus omitted it:
[Android Map V2 - Why MAPS_RECEIVE permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14832911/android-map-v2-why-maps-receive-permission)

READ_GSERVICES is detected as an unknown permission.

And here is my code:

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);


        //Create the user interface in code
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout (this);
        layout.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
        TextView txtKey = new TextView(this);
        txtKey.Text = "Your key is " + GetString(Resource.String.api_key_android);
        TextView txtNullCheck = new TextView (this);
        txtNullCheck.Text = "Map not null";

        //Create MapFragment and add it to this UI
        MapFragment myMapFrag = MapFragment.NewInstance();
        if (myMapFrag.Map != null) {
            FragmentTransaction fragTx = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
            fragTx.Add(layout.Id, myMapFrag);       
            fragTx.Commit();
        }
        else
        {
            txtNullCheck.Text = "Null GoogleMap";
        }


        layout.AddView(txtKey);
        layout.AddView(txtNullCheck);
        SetContentView(layout);




    }
```

Interestingly, if I omit the null check and just add the MapFragment the app will give me the message "Unfortunately, this app has stopped working" after a few seconds. Otherwise I will only get a null myMapFrag.Map and the MapFragment will not function as desired.

I'm currently testing this on a Galaxy Note 3.

I've been stumped on this for quite a while, and the documentation I've found hasn't been very helpful. So any help will be very appreciated!

Thanks,

~F

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the ENTIRE Manifest, can you please post it? It's almost always to do with missing entries in the Manifest.

Comment: Actually this is my AndroidManifest.xml in its entirety, copied and pasted. Is there something I'm missing? @KickAss