# Google Map Load Issue

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am working on integrating google maps in a small app. My `AndroidManifest.xml` is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mymaps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
<permission
        android:name="com.example.mymaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
 <uses-permission 
     android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
    <!-- Required to show current location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
 
    <!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"/>
    <uses-feature android:required="true"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.mymaps.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
     <meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
     android:value="MyKey" />
    </application>    
</manifest>
```

And my Main Activity is

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    TextView lat,lng;
    Button getCds,getMap;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initializeVars();
    }

    private void initializeVars() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getCds = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bGC);
        getMap = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bGM);
        lat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView2);
        lng = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView4);
        getCds.setOnClickListener(this);
        getMap.setOnClickListener(this);
        try {
            // Loading map
            initilizeMap(); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void initilizeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initilizeMap();
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("Debugging", "I am in onCLick");
        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.bGC:
        {
            Log.d("Debugging", "I am in case R.id.bGC");
            lat.setText("My Lat");
            lng.setText("My Long");
            break;
        }

        case R.id.bGM:
        {
            Log.d("Debugging", "I am in case R.id.bGM");
            lat.setText("blank");
            lng.setText("blank");
            break;
        }
        }
    }
}
```

When I Load the application I am getting the below error.

```
01-17 14:01:49.054: E/Google Maps Android API(2832): Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.
01-17 14:01:49.064: E/Google Maps Android API(2832): Ensure that the following correspond to what is in the API Console: Package Name: com.example.mymaps, API Key: MyKey, Certificate Fingerprint: SomeValue
01-17 14:01:49.064: I/Google Maps Android API(2832): Failed to contact Google servers. Another attempt will be made when connectivity is established.
01-17 14:01:59.234: D/dalvikvm(2832): GC_CONCURRENT freed 572K, 9% free 7576K/8263K, paused 6ms+3ms
01-17 14:02:04.304: E/Google Maps Android API(2832): Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).
```

Guys to give a little more perspective. The same code used to work before (probably 3-4 months back). It somehow doesn't seem to be working anymore. I am not sure what is causing the same.

Can you please advise how to debug the same?

Comment: you don't need `permission.MAPS_RECEIVE`. Google Play Services 3.1.59 made it useless. Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14832911/android-map-v2-why-maps-receive-permission

Comment: which version of the Google Play Services are you using?

Comment: where do I check that ? Sorry I am new, so don't know where to check the same.

Answer (score 1):

have a change from

```
<uses-permission 
     android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
```

to

```
<uses-permission 
     android:name="com.example.mymaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
```

I think the problem is with the key and it is not the correct one which you are using, Your API key in your manifest clearly does not match the API key you posted that is showing in the API console. Paste the API key from the console into the manifest. Should fix you right up.

you can  uninstall the app, and do a project clean, then re-install the app.. have a try with this but still it does not works  than

for more
please visit for the complete process for using new google map

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/

http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/12/android-google-maps-api-v2-example.html

**The best tutorial is**

http://codebybrian.com/2012/12/06/google_maps_android_v2_sample.html

Answer (score 0):

The `your.package.name.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE` is no longer needed. Please remove it from your manifest. Also you are missing this:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

It should be added within the `<application>` tag.