# Duplicate of an Android APP can not be installed while the original is still installed

Tags: android-studio, clone

I've been running an Android app in google playstore for several years now. Another customer would like to use this app tailored to his company also. So I copied the project folder and refectored the packages.

I did that on the basis of the following instructions:
[Android copy existing project with new name in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18324555/android-copy-existing-project-with-new-name-in-android-studio)

Before refectoring, the packagename was: at.myname.theappname
After refectoring, the new packagename is: at.myname.thenewappname

The application-id in build.grade (Module:app) and also the package in AndroidManifest.xml are changed and OK.
The app is using the google-map-api and in my desperation I took a new map-id for the app....

I signed the app with a new key and released it in google-playstore (at the moment in a closed beta-test).

So the problem is, both apps can not be installed at the same time. I checked that on several devices.
Once I have an app installed on my smartphone, I can not install the second one anymore. Once the old app is uninstalled, the new app can be easily installed.
It makes no difference if the old or the new app is on the smartphone. Once one of the two apps is installed, the other can not be installed.

It is interesting that the application-icon of the old app is still displayed on the smartphone even with the new app, although I have swapped the iconset (and cleand the cache and restarted the smartphone ...). However in settings-> apps the new icon is shown ...

The error message after trying to install from the playstore is not helpful - it only says that the app can not be installed.

What did I wrong?? What have I overlooked to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason myself.
I used the permisson com.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE which was used by my previous package already.
I removed this permission (look here: [Android Map V2 - Why MAPS_RECEIVE permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14832911/android-map-v2-why-maps-receive-permission) ) and it worked.

I do not know if it's the best solution, but it works in the first few tests.